# Automate configuration of Jenkins & Sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to find a solution to automate installation and configuration of Jenkins & SonarQube. The idea is to provide an easy to use provisioning utility for setting up CI. Ideally I would love to automate the following

1. Installation
2. Set up users,Build, Unit testing and Code coverage

Is there an SDK, CLI or similar which can be used from batch script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jenkins docker image for the installation part - even if you're not using Docker you can still copy the installation procedure:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker

For the setup of jobs I would recommend the Job DSL:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin

For the rest you can use the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) or you can manually configure it once and then extract the corresponding XML file from the Jenkins home and copy it into other installations.